# What is and how to fix the warning "missing required architecture arm64 in file" in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, makefile, theos

I've met a warning while learning to implement tweaks for jailbroken iOS with `theos`, in my trying, the warning disappeared if I remove `arm64` from the `ARCHS`, but obviously `arm64` can't be removed for supporting iPhone5s and above. Does anyone know why the warning appeared, and how can I fix it?

Makefile:

```
ARCHS = armv7 arm64

include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = Simple
Simple_FILES = Tweak.xm
Simple_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

Warning:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o, 
missing required architecture arm64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o (2 slices)
```

Comment: by just adding arm64 in "Valid Architectures" from Build Settings.

Comment: @V.J., I add `VALID_ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64` to `Makefile`, but doesn't work.